# Avoid inherited css

Tags: .net, html, css, razor

I have a div in which I am dynamically loading html that contains different elements with their css, this div is in partial view and its css is overriding div's element css.

like in partial view we have set css `table{border:none;}` but in div elements we want to show table css as it is defined in table element.

how can I achieve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a child selector.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.partial > table td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="partial">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you write css in partial view.

Instead of just writing `table {border: none;}` and override every table, you should do something like:

```
.partial-view-div table {
   border: solid 1px blue
}
```

Then it wouldn't override your `table` in other places.

Also [Read up on CSS Specificity score](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).